# Image delivery in socket communication between Android (Client) and C# (Server)

Tags: c#, android

Thanks for reading :]

When the current C# Socket server is opened and Android sends a message, the C# Server sends an image using a byteArray.

In Android, the size of the image was received normally, but BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() continues to return null. Thanks for your comments.

C# code

```
byte[] data = ImageToByteArray(this.pictureBox1.Image);

                        try
                        {
                            m_socket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length));
                            m_socket.Send(data);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                        }

public byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image image)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Android Code

```
 BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] data = new byte[4];
bis.read(data) // Img Size
int ilen = byteToInt(data); // byte[] to Int

byte[] data2 = new byte[ilen];
Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data2, 0, dta2.length); // Return null
imageView.setImageBitmap(bit);
```

Also, D/skia: --- png error bad adaptive filter value
d/skia: --- codec->getAndroidPixels() failed.

@_@....... Thank you!!

Comment: What does `ImageToByteArray`? What file format is contained in `data`? Have you confirmed that `data2` on the client side contains the exact same information as `data` in C# did?

Comment: `byte[] data = new byte[256];
bis.read(data) // Img Size` No that can never work. 256 bytes for a length? The server only needs to send four bytes for an integer that represents the length. So new byte[4]; would do. Ask the server man what is send. And how? Big endian? Little endian?

Comment: First check if you recieve the rigth length. Did you do so? Log and print the length.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!!

In android I got exactly the image byteArray length inside data. But when I try to convert byteArray to bitmap in data2, it returns null in bit variable.

Comment: Converts an image to a ByteArray in the current C# picturebox, and sends the length (data) and the data (data2) of the ByteArray using socket.send.

Comment: _"Converts an image to ByteArray in the current C# picturebox"_ - How? What file format does it use? Is that file format supported by `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`?

Comment: What file formats does BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray support? now

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return ms.ToArray();

Send in jpeg format.

And, when I change it to byte[] data = new byte[4] , I get an error saying "from Incomplete image data".

Comment: Pleas edit your question with that information.

Comment: If you save the image to a file, and then load the bytes of that file in on the Android side, does `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` work on the data loaded from file? I'm curious to know if this is a transport issue or an inherent issue with the data itself.